# Numbers changes after list repetition?

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I have this function:

```
def generateRepetition(toR, rate):
    return [toR]*rate
```

If I call it with `toR=0.234` the function returns an array in which the number is repeated for rate parameter, however, the number changes in this way:

```
[0.23399999999999999, 0.23399999999999999, 0.23399999999999999,...]
```

I do not understand why, anybody has a solution?

Comment: @alfasin I read the OP's issue was with the floating point results.

Comment: @AChampion you're right - my bad